# How can I make stellarjs work with webpack?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, stellar.js

I'm using webpack to handle my js task.
Now I import [stellajs](https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js) in my main script by this:

`import $ from 'jquery';`

`require('imports?define=>false!./jquery.stellar');`

Or

`import $ from 'jquery';`

`import './jquery.stellar';`

But I always got

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).stellar is not a
>   function

How can I use jquery stella in webpack.
Thank you!